# What does $status refer to in a C shell?

Tags: c, shell, csh

I'm trying to recreate a basic C Shell like tcsh, but I'm having understanding the variable `$status`.  This is an example of status in `tcsh`:

A command that exists:

```
$> pwd
/home/user
$> echo $status
0
```

A command that doesn't exist:

```
$> foo
foo: Command not found.
$> echo $status
1
```

What do the values of status refer to? Return values from tcsh?

Comment: You know that you can exit from a C program using the `exit` function, or by returning from the `main` function? The value you pass to `exit` or use with the `return` statement is the exit code of the process, and what is returned and used for the `$status` tcsh variable. tcsh also have some special statuses, like what is used when no program is found (like in your example). What status to use and set in the special cases is up to you.

Comment: http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Special_shell_variables.html#status

Comment: yes i am aware of that, but since i'm recreating a shell interpreter, i will be using an infinite loop to run my code and wait for the user input, if i return a value from the main or use exit function it will terminate my program

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: `tcsh` didn't exit, so it didn't return anything (yet). `$status`is a variable. It holds the status of the last command executed by `tcsh`. When that last command succeeds, the status is 0. In other cases,it's non-zero. You can view it as the value returned *by* `pwd` or `foo` *to* `tcsh`.

Comment: oh i understand now, it's clearer thank you very much ^_^

Comment: By the way the C shell and its spawn should all ~~~expletive deleted~~~ die. Source: used them for 10+ years.

Comment: @n.m., there are much better sources than your personal experience on that. http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot and http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt are both classics.

Comment: Why do you think "not exiting [the] function" happens here? Just because the shell doesn't exit as a whole doesn't mean that whatever function it called to execute its builtin (or call out to an external command) didn't complete. But even that's moot, since what's happening is an update to global state.

Comment: Well i'm a bit new to C but since i'm executing everything in my main, my program will terminate as soon as i return something, so i should find another way that is more practical.

Comment: There are tens of thousands of text about shells and examples on how to implement one, all over the Internet (including probably thousands of related questions here on SO). I'm sorry to sound rude, but if you did just a *teeny* amount of research you would know about the `fork`/`exec`/wait` cycle.

Comment: I understand ^_^ though i did understand the cycle you're talking about, i fork to create the child process, and execute my commands with one of the exec family functions, and wait for the end of the child process on the parent process, it was just a little confusion over the return value on success and on failure :) but i got it good now, my program functions as expected, and thanks for the remarks, helps me to improve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$status` or `$?` means the exit status of the previously started command. To put it more precisely, the exit status of the child process. Because in case of a not existing command, there is a forked child shell, but it fails to `exec()` the command.

Shells usually start a command like this:

```
int pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {   /* Child shell process */
    /* Try to replace child shell with cmd, in same child PID */
    /* cmd will generate the exit status of child process */
    execve(cmd, argv, envp);

    /* If execve returns, it's always an error */
    /* Child shell generates exit status for error */
    write(2, "command not found\n", 18);
    exit(127);
} else {          /* Parent shell process */
    /* Original shell waits for child to exit */
    int status;
    wait(&status); /* Assuming only one child */

    /* this is accessible in shell as $status or $? */
    status = WEXITSTATUS(status);
}
```